# Total number of posts?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to figure out how to display the total number of posts in a category (or all together). I envision something like below, but can't quite figure it out. Did I miss something from the docs?

```
{% for post in site.categories.CAT %}
    ...do some counting
{% endfor %}

posts: {% number_of_posts %}

{% for post in site.categories.CAT %}
    {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% for post in site.categories.CAT %}
   {% capture post_count %} {{ post_count | plus: 1 }} {% endcapture %}
{% endfor %}
{{ post_count }}
```

Answer (score 23):

```
# all posts

{{ site.posts | size }}

# posts in one category

{{ site.categories.CAT | size }}
```

Comment: How do you know this? I'm new to ruby and octopress. I find it very hard to find any info, Octopress doesn't tell much

Comment: This isn't Ruby, it's Liquid.